# How can I make a vegan turkey-skin substitute?

Tags: vegetarian, vegan, turkey, thanksgiving

I recently tried to practice making a Seitan based vegan turkey tube using [this recipe](http://harekrishnawomen.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/seitan-turkey-recipe/). To test results for different cooking methods, I split the final dough in half before baking, made one that was just turkey-dough and one that was a turkey-dough and stuffing roulade.

Both turkey loaves came out well. However, the recipe gives instructions on fabricating a kind of "turkey skin." Basically, once the turkey is done baking, remove from oven, place on a pan, wrap with *yuba* (bean-curd skin from making soy milk, similar to spring roll pastry), brush with sesame oil, and bake until browned (about 45-60 minutes, brushing on more oil occasionally). The results were basically a distracting pastry shell wrapped around a seitan loaf; it did not appear to adhere to the surface of the loaf at any point. It was difficult to cut and had a difficult texture compared to the ease of the seitan.

To give an idea of the results, here is a picture of some scraps from the plate:

[image]

The instructions did not give a specific detail as to what to expect, or really how to qualify the results of the "turkey skin." As such, I am at a loss as to how to improve the results.

So:

- Have you made or had a *yuba* wrapped item, where the method above was somehow applied but with a more successful result (as in, the *yuba* adhered to the surface of the loaf, the yuba cut easily, or had a more delicate texture that didn't contrast as much)?
- Of the three fails (adherence, cutting, texture), what methods would work to improve them? (E.G. Would brushing oil on the loaf before help or hinder yuba sticking to the loaf, would it help soften the yuba?)
- Is there any method of softening the *yuba* and making it more delicate before applying it? Would this be beneficial to the desired result? Why?
- Could tweaking the temp:time of baking with the yuba wrap help? (i.e. Lower-slower breaks down fats, connective tissues in animals... is there a similar compound I am shooting for in yuba?)
- Can *yuba* be prepared to mimic the soft-toughness of turkey skin? How?

Comment: While I can appreciate the effort you are going through here, and the amount of skill that is involved, I'm wondering why, if you are preparing a vegan meal, you are trying so hard to make something that is like something completely un-vegan?  Seems like a lot of effort for not much.

Comment: @JenniferS because it is there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either get fresh or dried yuba, the dried one has to be soaked.

When I made a tofu turkey I soaked the yuba sheat for about 10 minutes in warm water before wrapping it around the "meat". The tofu turkey had already been baking in the oven for around 1 hour when I added the skin. After applying the yuba I rosted the whole thing in the oven until the skin was brown (maybe 30 minutes), brushing occationally with marinade. Skin came out perfect and had a nice crispyness without coming apart from the tofu or being too brittle.

Oh, yeah, I brushed the tofu alternatively with marinade and with melted vegan butter every 15 minutes or so before adding the yuba. It might have made a difference but I really think soaking the sheats is key. 
Good luck!

I made a video guide to making a vegan "tofurkey" from tofu.
Here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKIrgls-WCw

[image: tofu turkey being brushed with butter prior to adding the skinn]

[image: tofu turkey after adding soy skinn]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was hoping someone would have experience with this. What was the temperature that you were baking at? Also, were you using Earth Balance margarine, or something else?

Comment: I was baking it at around 200°C. I live in Germany and I was using a german brand of margarine. I'm sure Earth Balance will work fine!